# Natvis C++ formatting for a custom type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, natvis

I have been trying to create a natvis file for VS2019 C++ for a derived variable.  I have built libraries from the NDK although I don't think that should matter.

Here is a screen snip:

[image: While debugging]

Can you give me some hints on how to at least start visualising it?  My attempts so far have had zero effect.  I admit I find reading template style variables difficult.

My current attempt:
It is derived from std::string (take a look at the snip).

My attempt is:

```
<Type Name="std::__ndk1::*&lt;char,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">{_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf,na}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">{_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr,na}</DisplayString>
    <StringView Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf,na</StringView>
    <StringView Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr,na</StringView>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[size]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize</Item>
      <Item Name="[capacity]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair._Myval2._Myres</Item>
      <Item Name="[allocator]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair</Item>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Size>_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize</Size>
        <ValuePointer Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf</ValuePointer>
        <ValuePointer Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

Comment: please show a [mre] with the class you are trying to visualise and the natvis file you've created so far

Comment: I edited the original post

Comment: What is the class you're trying to visualise? Please show a [mre]

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Did you enable debugging of natvis and look into the output window?